# Leaflet: Change marker icon for all markers in layer on event

Tags: reactjs, leaflet

I have several layerGroups and I want marker icons in one specific layerGroup to be changed depending on some event. For example switch to more detailed marker icon.

```
const iconBig = () =>
  L.divIcon({
    className: "big",
    html: `<div><div>`,
    iconSize: [30, 30],
    iconAnchor: [15, 15]
  });

const iconSmall = () =>
  L.divIcon({
    className: "small",
    html: `<div><div>`,
    iconSize: [30, 30],
    iconAnchor: [15, 15]
  });

const a = L.layerGroup();

let marker1 = latlng =>
  L.marker(latlng, {
    icon: iconBig()
  });

a.addLayer(marker1([12, 3]));
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Something like this - set icon for all markers in `markerGroup a` to `iconSmall` :

```
a.eachLayer(function(layer) {
   if( layer instanceof L.Marker ) {
     layer.setIcon(iconSmall);
    }
});
```